# how to remove an uploaded images

Tags: vue.js

Here I have tried to remove a uploaded images. Like while if user clicks on any of the images which is uploaded by the user if we click on cross icon it has to remove the images. So below is my code where I have tried and I am able to remove the image but at once multiple images are removing i need to remove only selected images not multiple so how can we do that. all images should have cross icon at the top corner. Please

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      files: [],
      images: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filesNames() {
      const fn = []
      for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; ++i) {
        fn.push(this.files.item(i).name)
      }
      return fn
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleFileUploads(event) {
      this.files = event.target.files;
      this.images = [...this.files].map(URL.createObjectURL);
    },
    
    removeImage: function () {
        this.images = null
      },

    submitFile() {
      let formData = new FormData();
      for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        let file = this.files[i];
        formData.append('files[' + i + ']', file);
      }

      axios.post('/multiple-files', formData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
        }).then(function() {
          console.log('SUCCESS!!');
        })
        .catch(function() {
          console.log('FAILURE!!');
        });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Multiple Files</h2>
  <hr/>
  <label>
    <span>Files</span>
    <input type="file" multiple @change="handleFileUploads($event)" />
    <ul v-if="files.length">
      <li v-for="(name, i) in filesNames" :key="i">{{ name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </label>
  <div>
    <img v-for="image in images" :src="image" />
    <button v-if="images" @click="removeImage()" type="button">×</button>
    
  </div>
  <br />
  <button @click="submitFiles()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Well you have `this.files` and `this.images` as an array, correct? So if you have the index of the file to be removed as parameter... then how about [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)?

Comment: sorry but i did not get you

Comment: Well which part do you not understand?

Comment: so. Here this.files and this.images are arrays. So my issue is user uploads a multiple images. So in that all the images should Have cancel or cross icon so that user can able to delete any of the images. So in my above code I have tried but in that while i am clicking on cross icon all the images are deleting.

Comment: Well yes, all images are deleting since you do this in `removeImage`: `this.images = null`. Instead of setting them null, you could give `removeImage` the index of the image to be removed and it would splice it out of the array of images. Please try and implement something.

Comment: sure thank you i will try to implement